# AngularJS ng-repeat is slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is not like it is slow on rendering many entries. The problem is that whenever the `$scope.data` got updated, it adds the new item first at the end of the element, then reduce it as it match the new `$scope.data`.

For example:

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="entry in data">
    <h3>{{entry.title}}</h3>
</div>
```

This script is updating the `$scope.data`:

```
$scope.load = function() {
    $scope.data = getDataFromDB();
}
```

Lets say I have 5 entries inside `$scope.data`. The entries are:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 1
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 2
    },
    ......
]
```

When the `$scope.data` already has those entries then got reloaded (`$scope.data = getDataFromDB();` being called), the DOM element for about 0.1s - 0.2s has 10 elements (duplicate elements), then after 0.1s - 0.2s it is reduced to 5.

So the problem is that there is delay about 0.1s - 0.2s when updating the ng-repeat DOM. This looks really bad when I implement live search. Whenever it updates from the database, the ng-repeat DOM element got added up every time for a brief millisecond.

How can I make the rendering instant?

---

### EDITED

I will paste all my code here:

The controller:

```
$scope.search = function (table) {
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.endOfPage = false;
    $scope.viewModels = [];
    $scope.loadViewModels($scope.orderBy, table);
}

$scope.loadViewModels = function (orderBy, table, cb) {
    if (!$scope.endOfPage) {
        let searchKey = $scope.page.searchString;
        let skip = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;
        let searchClause = '';

        if (searchKey && searchKey.length > 0) {
            let searchArr = [];
            $($scope.vmKeys).each((i, key) => {
                searchArr.push(key + ` LIKE '%` + searchKey + `%'`);
            });
            searchClause = `WHERE ` + searchArr.join(' OR ');
        }

        let sc = `SELECT * FROM ` + table + ` ` + searchClause + ` ` + orderBy +
            ` LIMIT ` + skip + `, ` + $scope.itemsPerPage;
        sqlite.query(sc, rows => {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                var data = [];
                let loadedCount = 0;
                if (rows != null) {
                    $scope.currentPage += 1;
                    loadedCount = rows.length;
                    if (rows.length < $scope.itemsPerPage)
                        $scope.endOfPage = true

                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        let item = rows.item(i);
                        let returnObject = {};
                        $($scope.vmKeys).each((i, key) => {
                            returnObject[key] = item[key];
                        });
                        data.push(returnObject);
                    }
                    $scope.viewModels = $scope.viewModels.concat(data);
                } 
                else
                    $scope.endOfPage = true;

                if (cb)
                    cb(loadedCount);
            })
        });
    }
}
```

The view:

```html
<div id="pageContent" class="root-page" ng-controller="noteController" ng-cloak>
    <div class="row note-list" ng-if="showList">
        <h3>Notes</h3>
        <input ng-model="page.searchString" id="search"
               ng-keyup="search('notes')" type="text" class="form-control"
               placeholder="Search Notes" style="margin-bottom:10px">
        <div class="col-12 note-list-item"
             ng-repeat="data in viewModels track by data.id"
             ng-click="edit(data.id)"
             ontouchstart="touchStart()" ontouchend="touchEnd()"
             ontouchmove="touchMove()">
            <p ng-class="deleteMode ? 'note-list-title w-80' : 'note-list-title'"
               ng-bind-html="data.title"></p>
            <p ng-class="deleteMode ? 'note-list-date w-80' : 'note-list-date'">{{data.dateCreated | displayDate}}</p>
            <div ng-if="deleteMode" class="note-list-delete ease-in" ng-click="delete($event, data.id)">
                <span class="btn fa fa-trash"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="!deleteMode" ng-click="new()" class="add-btn btn btn-primary ease-in">
            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="!showList" class="ease-in">
        <div>
            <div ng-click="back()" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span></div>
            <div ng-disabled="!isDataChanged" ng-click="save()" class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right">
                <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="note-title"
             ng-bind-html="selected.title" id="title">
        </div>
        <div contenteditable="true" class="note-container" ng-bind-html="selected.note" id="note"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="../js/pages/note.js"></script>
```

Calling it from:

```
$scope.loadViewModels($scope.orderBy, 'notes');
```

The sqlite query:

```
query: function (query, cb) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(query, [], function (tx, res) {
            return cb(res.rows, null);
        });
    }, function (error) {
        return cb(null, error.message);
    }, function () {
        //console.log('query ok');
    });
},
```

It is apache cordova framework, so it uses webview in Android emulator.

---

### My Code Structure

```
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="pageController">
    <head>....</head>
    <body>
        ....
        <div id="pageContent" class="root-page" ng-controller="noteController" ng-cloak>
            ....
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So there is controller inside controller. The parent is `pageController` and the child is `noteController`. Is a structure like this slowing the `ng-repeat` directives?

Btw using `track by` is not helping. There is still delay when rendering it. Also I can modify the entries as well, so when an entry was updated, it should be updated in the list as well.

---

### NOTE

After thorough investigation there is something weird. Usually ng-repeat item has `hash` key in it. In my case ng-repeat items do not have it. Is it the cause of the problem?

Comment: Each time the value in ```$scope.data``` is replaced whenever it updates from the database. Right?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thorough research, I found my problem. Every time I reset / reload my `$scope.viewModels` I always assign it to `null / empty array` first. This what causes the render delay.

Example:

```
$scope.search = function (table) {
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.endOfPage = false;
    $scope.viewModels = []; <------ THIS
    $scope.loadViewModels($scope.orderBy, table);
}
```

So instead of assigning it to null / empty array, I just replace it with the new loaded data, and the flickering is gone.

Answer (score 2):

One approach to improve performance is to use the `track by` clause in the `ng-repeat` expression:

```html
<div class="list" ng-repeat="entry in data track by entry.id">
    <h3>{{entry.title}}</h3>
</div>
```

From the Docs:

> **Best Practice:** If you are working with objects that have a unique identifier property, you should track by this identifier instead of the object instance, e.g. `item in items track by item.id`. Should you reload your data later, `ngRepeat` will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones. For large collections, **this significantly improves rendering performance.**

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ngRepeat API Reference -- Tracking and Duplicates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#tracking-and-duplicates)

Comment: I tried this, still the same result. Also what happened if the item with that id is changed? will it be changed in the DOM or will it preserve the old values?

Answer (score 0):

In your html, try this:

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="entry in data">
    <h3 ng-bind="entry.title"></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: it does not work, still the same performance